# git clone vs cp -R

Tags: git, unix, shell, bash

I want to use an existing project as a starting point for a new project by copying or cloning it.

There are at least two ways of doing this.

Method 1: Copy it.

```
cp -R /path/to/source /path/to/dest
```

and

Method 2: Clone it.

```
git clone /path/to/source
```

What are the relative advantages and disadvantages of each approach compared to the other? Or do they both produce essentially exactly the same result?

Comment: Well, `cp -R https://github.com/stuff` won't work.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Understood. Aside from that, though, are there any differences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying copies the working copy, any untracked files, and any local configuration along with the actual repository.

Cloning doesn't, but it sets up the origin remote with a tracking branch.

Use copying if you want to duplicate your repository so that all remote operations work the same. Use cloning if you want to create a subordinate repository to your original.

Answer (score 3):

This is not strictly an answer to you question, but if you want to start a new project, do you really want to copy all the history, branches, etc from the old project?

If you just want a working template, say to get the structure of the project as a starting point, but it should have no other ties to the original, then clone the repo but delete the .git folder and run `git init` again to start fresh.

Comment: From the poster's intention, it shows that the project would be a template so  your comment makes more sense.